# C++: How to use different dynamic template in map

Tags: c++, dictionary, templates

my header code:

```
template <typename T>
    class A
    {
    
    }
    
    template<> class A<short>;
    template<> class A<float>;
```

in my cpp, i want to use a map to contain different type a, like following code:

```
 class B
{
    map<int, A*> a; /* how to declare a */
public:
    AddA(int key, int type)
    {
        if (type == 1)
        {
            a.insert({ key, new A<short>() });
        }
        else
        {
            a.insert({ key, new A<float>() });
        }
    }
    template<typename T>
    func(int key, T v)
    {
        a[key].func(v);
    }
};
```

question: how to implement it?

edit @ 0410, here is my solution:

```
class ABase
{
virtual void func(void* t)=0;
}

template <typename T> A;
template <short> A : public ABase
{
    void func(void* t) override
    {
auto value = *static_cast<short*>(t);
// do processing
}
template <float> A : public ABase
{
    void func(void* t) override
    {
auto value = *static_cast<float*>(t);
// do processing
}
```

CPP: used a map of ABase* for all the template class, and use a virtual func for all template interface

```
main()
{
map<int, ABase*> objs;
objs.insert({0, new A<short>()});
objs.insert({1, new A<float>()});
auto value=0;
objs[0]->func(&value);
auto value1=0.f;
objs[1]->func(&value1);
}
```

Comment: Code like yours (where you select type depending on some magic number) is a typical design smell. How is `B` supposed to be used? Can it be a template itself?

Comment: `A<T>::func` is missing, but it seems to play an important role. Is it declared as `A<T>::func(T t)` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you *really* need to have multiple types in a single map, you can use a map of `std::variant`. But as already mentioned in the comments, this might be a design problem.

But if you need it, you can proceed with the `std::map< int, std::variant<>>`. Later on, if you want to access the stored element, you have to call `std::visit` to pick the element which is stored in `std::variant`.

See the following example:

```
template < typename T >
struct A
{
};

// spezialize if needed, here only for demonstration purpose
template <> struct A<short> { void func(short parm) { std::cout << "A<short> with " << parm << std::endl; } }; 
template <> struct A<float> { void func(float parm) { std::cout << "A<float> with " << parm << std::endl; } }; 


class B
{
    std::map<int, std::variant<A<short>*, A<float>*>> a; 
    public:
    void AddA(int key, int type)
    {    
        if (type == 1)
        {
            a.insert({ key, new A<short>() });
        }
        else
        {
            a.insert({ key, new A<float>() });
        }
    }    
    template<typename T>
        void func(int key, T v) 
        {
            std::visit( [&v]( auto ptr ) { ptr->func(v); }, a[key] );
        }
};

int main()
{
    B b; 
    b.AddA( 1, 1 ); 
    b.AddA( 2, 2 ); 

    b.func( 1, 99 );
    b.func( 2, 100 );
}
```

Comment: In fact, I want to solve a problem that has been bothering me for a long time. I'm trying to encapsulate a dynamic library that can be used for different data types, but the data type is determined by the data file opened by the user. The processing of different data types is not the same, so the unified code cannot be used, so how can I design a general template class to implement it?

Comment: OK, I see what you mean, but this question has nothing to do with so. I just hope to get a more perfect answer. I edited the problem again and gave my own solution, hoping to get more suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

You can't achieve the problem with templates. Template declaration is only a blueprint for a type candidate.

"A<short>" is the type not "A" itself.

You can achieve your problem through inheritance.

Edit: Code is updated according to @MSalters' comment. Thanks.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <map>

class A 
{
public:
  virtual void func(void* x) = 0;
};

class A_Short : public A
{ 
public: 
  void func(void* x)
  {
    short* value = static_cast<short*>(x);
    std::cout << "short value: " << *value << std::endl;
  } 
};

class A_Float  : public A
{ 
public: 
  void func(void* x)
  {
    float* value = static_cast<float*>(x);

    std::cout << "float value: " << *value << std::endl;
  } 
};

template<typename T>
class A_Derived : public A
{ 
public: 
  void func(void* x)
  {
    T* value = static_cast<T*>(x);
    std::cout << "[Derived] value: " << *value << std::endl;
  } 
};

class B
{
    std::map<int, A*> a; /* how to declare a */
public:
    void AddA(int key, int type)
    {
        if (type == 1)
        {
            a.insert({ key, new A_Short() });
        }
    else if(type == 2)
    {
            a.insert({key, new A_Derived<short>()});
    }
    else if(type == 3)
    {
            a.insert({key, new A_Derived<float>()});
    }
        else
        {
            a.insert({ key, new A_Float() });
        }
    }

    // Assumes that user knows to use which T for any "key"
    template<typename T>
    void func(int key, T v)
    {
        a[key]->func(v);
    }
};




int main()
{
  B b;

  b.AddA(1, 1);
  b.AddA(2, 8);
  b.AddA(3, 2);
  b.AddA(4, 3);
  
  
  short s = 1;
  float f = 7.1;
  short s2 = 2;
  float f2 = 7.2;

  b.func(1, &s);
  b.func(2, &f);
  b.func(3, &s2);
  b.func(4, &f2);
}
```

Comment: This is misleading - it correctly shows that base classes can solve the problem, but incorrectly assumes that the derived types can't be templates. You can in fact define `template <class T> A_Derived : public A`.